# How parse web page and get indicated content

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, xmlhttprequest, stock

I want parse selected web page: [KGHM](https://kghm.com/). I need actual price stock price. On server side I wrote simple programme, which storage and calculate stock market data. For the program to work properly, it must update prices and calculate the value of the wallet.

I consider to usage:

- [node-XMLHttpRequest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest)
- [dom-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dom-parser)

I wrote test script but I can't get access to data in concrete selector.

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var DOMParser = require('dom-parser');

const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', 'https://kghm.com/pl', false);   
req.send(null);
if(req.status == 200) 
   var parser = new DOMParser();
   var htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(req.responseText);

console.log(htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("cell price"))
```

Maybe this is not good solution.

Function return:

```
[
  Node { namespace: null, text: undefined, _selfCloseTag: false },
  Node { namespace: null, text: undefined, _selfCloseTag: false },
  Node { namespace: null, text: undefined, _selfCloseTag: false }
]
```

Comment: Probably the CORS policy is preventing you from sending requests to that page ...

Comment: Script download page, console.log show all page content but I can use HTML DOM method:

**`console.log(htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("cell price"))`**

`[
  Node { namespace: null, text: undefined, _selfCloseTag: false },
  Node { namespace: null, text: undefined, _selfCloseTag: false },
  Node { namespace: null, text: undefined, _selfCloseTag: false }
]`

Comment: Well does not work for me - can you please provide at least a working example here or on jsFiddle?

Comment: I trying to use node application with npm modules. I can't running it online. I'm beginner. How import npm modules in online editor?

Comment: This could also be just pure JavaScript somewhere on JSFiddle